# Error on Migration when adding SQL functions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have the following 2 files:

**20161009180554_add_process_functionst_to_db.rb**

```
class AddProcessFunctionstToDb < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    funcs = File.read(Rails.root.join('db', 'migrate', 'processfunctions.sql').to_s)
    execute funcs
  end
end
```

**processfunctions.sql**

```
drop function if exists retention_data(ref refcursor, shopId integer);
create or replace function retention_data(ref refcursor, shopId integer) returns refcursor as $$
    begin
...
    return ref;
    end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I am trying to add the function in processfunctions.sql to the database. But when I run

```
rake db:migrate
```

I get the following error:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "﻿"
LINE 1: ﻿
        ^
: ﻿
drop function if exists retention_data(ref refcursor, shopId integer);
```

after 'Line 1: ' in the error (what the arrow is pointing at) is a rectangle. Like what you would see if you didn't have the right font installed.

I have removed the blank line on line 1 and changed from CRLF to LF, but neither of those changed anything

Comment: Does `processfunctions.sql` contain what you think it does? Maybe have a look at it with `cat -vet` or look at a hex dump.

Comment: Cool, that worked! Thanks